# How can I change the display order of posts in the category? (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Categories display posts by publication date.
How can I change the display of posts based on the most visited?
Also select the number of posts displayed?
My code:

```
<?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        if( have_posts() ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post(); ?>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'card2' ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; // End of the loop.
        }
        else { ?>
            <div class="col-12 text-center pb-5">
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'empty' ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need to provide us with your "query". The code you've provided simply doesn't show anything except a generic wordpress loop! In order to get the data you're looking for you need to make a query to the database with the arguments you want to specify. Without seeing your query it's impossible to debug and/or make suggestions.

Comment: how can i please help me